# How do I use pandas to open file and process each row for that file?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe containing image filenames and multiple (X, Y) coordinates for each image, like this::

| file | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File1 | 1 | 2 |
| File1 | 103 | 6 |
| File2 | 6 | 3 |
| File2 | 4 | 9 |

I want to open each file and draw the points points on it.

I want to open each file in the file column once only. (I know how to open and draw on the file, I am asking how to loop through the dataframe correctly). Then process each line for that file.

I know I can use perhaps `df['file'].unique()` but don't know where to go from that.

I can probably work this out naively but is there a clever pandas way of doing it? I imagine it may have been asked but I can't figure out how to search for it.

Comment: you can iterate over a `df.groupby` object - in this case `for file, group_df in df.groupby('file')`

Comment: Thanks, so how do I then process each row? Ah is that group_df ?

Comment: yes `group_df` would be the dataframe for that particular file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group all the rows into separate dataframes for each unique value of the `file` columns, loop over those dataframes, and use `iterrows` on each dataframe to loop over each row.

```py
for file, group_df in df.groupby('file'):
    print(f'{file}:')
    for idx, row in group_df.iterrows():
        x, y = row[['x', 'y']]
        print(f'  x={x} y={y}')
```

Output:

```py
File1:
  x=1 y=2
  x=103 y=6
File2:
  x=6 y=3
  x=4 y=9
```